# QGIS 2.4 layout view PDF/raster file export moves points

Tags: qgis, point, export, pdf, layouts

I created a map, using a Google basemap (OpenLayers plugin) and imported a table as a CSV file (containing a name of a city, latitude, longitude for wgs84 and a row named "amount"). It displays correctly also in the layout view but when I export the Layout the points are moved to the east while the base map stays where it should. I tried to convert the wgs84 coordinates of my CSV file by saving it as a shapefile (defining the coordinate system as wgs84 Pseudo Mercator) but that did not work either.

The points in my map are still moved after exporting from the layout view. I am working on this for 6 hours now and I am getting crazy.

Could anybody please please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I went through this last year, and using the OpenLayers basemaps for print-ready exports does not seem to work. I think its the basemap tiles that are moving, and not your points...

I would recommend, and you will love the result in terms of quality as much as what you learned, to follow the steps @underdark has put together here:

[A guide to GoogleMaps-like maps with OSM in QGIS](http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/)

Which basically entails using OSM data you can download from [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/), load them into SQLite as per the instructions, then apply the [QGIS style files](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/qgis2/osm_spatialite) she has graciously created and shared.

I recently created maps for a city-wide tour of historic sites (Doors Open), with the result going into a printed brochure. Here's a snap of the big map:

[image]

The result is a print-quality map with beautiful colour at any resolution...

Many thanks to Anita for providing this method and style files!

Comment: Great thank you so far. I haven't checked back on my answer because I went for custom styled OSM Data instead using google base map. Thanks for the guide I will have a look into it as soon as possible!